# Using more than 1 google map in android in the same application

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile

in my application i'm using 2 maps each one has a different purpose, when i run my application it works great and when i run the first map(a) it runs correctly , when i run the second one(b) it runs correctly too but the problem is if i want to get back to the first one(a) again ,it displays the other map(b) !! and the 2 maps now display the same thing!!

note : the order of maps execution doesn't matter because as soon as i run map(b) ,map(a) will display map(b) every time!!
map(a) will display correctly only before i run map(b)!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a bit of a weird one. The Solution.

Have your second activity with the second map use a different process name. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc

```
<activity
  android:name=".Activity1">
</activity>

<activity
  android:name=".Activity2"
  android:process=":Map2">
</activity>
```

The `:` defines the process as private to the application, which you want. (Unless you want other App's potentially using that process).

The one downside? This will use more resources for your app. Think if you really need two map instances?

If one is just a static map view showing a pin in a map. Consider something like the Google Map Static requests. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Regards,
Chris

Comment: With the above code, you will have 3 processes running. Two which you have defined and one being the default process of the app. SO instead of defining the process attribute in both the activities, just define it once in either of the map activities, the other map is already in a separate process (the default process).